# Shutdown Foreground Service from tap notification action

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, foreground-service

I have an app that uses a `ForegroundService` and a `BroadcastReceiver`.
When the app is started, the `ForegroundService` is started too and the mandatory notification is sent to user to notify that such a service is running. Based on the App's way to work, Service needs to run indefinetely but i would like that the user could eventually shutdown the Service using a `TapAction` on this notification.
Actually i achieved this result sending an explicit `Intent` to `BroadcastReceiver` and then on the `onReceive()` method send another explicit `Intent` to the `ForegroundService` to shut it down with `stopService()` method.
I was wondering if there is a way to send directly an `Intent` from `TapAction` to `ForegroundService` considering that there is no `onReceive()` method on `Service`